# Multi-org consideration: Multi-org doesn’t support custom fields in webcollect

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am enabling multi-org for SFMC. During the configuration I came across this comment in Salesforce help: *Multi-org doesn’t support custom fields in webcollect, which means, if the form contains custom fields, we can’t collect the data supplied by the subscribers.*

Does this means after enabling multi-org, we cannot create new fields in landing/cloud pages (to collect data in data extensions) that are not standard fields in synchronized data extensions? Please clarify.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_upgrade_to_multi-org.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling multi-org in Salesforce Marketing Cloud does not affect the ability to create new fields in data extensions or capture data on cloud pages to be saved in these data extensions.

However, it should be noted that the feature [Web Collect](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_email_studio_web_collect.htm&type=5) which is an old feature and not commonly used in practice, does not support custom fields in multi-org configuration.